# We hurt without moving

Tags: riddle

We hurt without moving.
We poison without touching.
We bear the truth and the lies.
We are not to be judged by our size.

What are we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be

> words

We hurt without moving.

> Words may hurt, but do not move

We poison without touching.

> Words may poison relationships, but do not touch

We bear the truth and the lies.

> Words can state truth and lies

We are not to be judged by our size.

> Small print and block capitals: words always mean the same

Answer (score 3):

> Letters

hurt without moving.
poison without touching.
bear the truth and the lies.
are not to be judged by their size.