# Riddle Time. I bet this is an easy one

Tags: riddle

1. I can only live when there is Light but I die if the Light shines on me. What am I?
2. I hurt without moving. I poison without touching. I bear the truth and the lies. I am not to be judged by my size. What am I?
3. You can carry it everywhere you go, and it does not get heavy. What is it?
4. Name an eight letter word that has kst in the middle, in the beginning, and at the end.

Comment: I Think number 1 is a dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We hurt without moving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/we-hurt-without-moving)

Comment: @KevinL A for your effort finding that post. LOL

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please note that, like on other Stack Exchange, it's best to ask one question/riddle at the time, unless they are somehow connected with each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.

> It is a shadow. Dies in the light but cannot exist without light

2.

> Words. They can really hurt someone else just by saying bad stuff. They can be used to either lie or tell the truth. Size does not matter.

3.

> It's my own name. Not heavy and I carry it everywhere

4.

> Inkstand. Has "kst" in the middle, "in" in the beginning, and "and" in the end

Comment: I haven't looked at your answers, yet I haven't received a comment of mine being a duplicate, so I will stick with mine... but for now, assuming your answer is good, I will $(+1)$ :P

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow are my answers correct or are they wrong?

Comment: I finally looked at your answer after I answered every single one, and nearly all of my answers are different, hahah! How did I not think of your answer for 1? :P

Comment: Lol isn't ur answer to number 3 the same as mine :) @user477343

Comment: Yeah that's the only one that's the same :P

Comment: I searched the site and it looks like almost every one of OP's questions is a dupe. The riddle is also not his I believe. You can just type the same thing on the internet and find thousands of similar results

Answer (score 3):

For no. 4, I think it is

> inkstand, kst in the middle, "in" is the beginning, "and" is the end

Comment: Sorry mate answered first :)

Comment: I need times to make sure it is really english word :)

Comment: Edit history backs it up... and it is an english word :D

Answer (score 3):

1.

> **Shadow.** 
>  [A chestnut.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56147/i-can-only-live-where-there-is-light)

2.

> **Words.** 
>  Words can hurt (verbal abuse), poison (hurt), Words can lie or tell the truth. Words are not to be judged by size. 
>  [A chestnut.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/we-hurt-without-moving)

Answer (score 2):

1.

`I can only live when there is Light but I die if the Light shines on me. What am I?`

> A **lie**? You can **li**ve when there is **li**ght (light being the **truth**; without the truth, there is nothing to lie about). But lies die when the truth is revealed (i.e. when the light **shines** on it). I have to thank Riddle 2 for this :P

2.

`I hurt without moving. I poison without touching. I bear the truth and the lies. I am not to be judged by my size. What am I?`

> **Death**? Funerals **hurt** because they are sad; people can become **depressed** (a poison) from the death of certain people; and it bears the truth and lies (because people can **fake** their death). (I was thinking of **words**, but it is said that they can "move" and/or "touch" you.)

3.

`You can carry it everywhere you go, and it does not get heavy. What is it?`

> <s>**Shoes**?</s> (Was going to say **eyes** or a **heart**, but they can get "heavy".) Alas! It's a **name**! The first word of Riddle 4 gave this away :P

4.

`Name an eight letter word that has kst in the middle, in the beginning, and at the end.`

> **Backstab**? It has "kst" in the back (end) and in the stab (beginning); informally, a stab can refer to the attempt of doing something (but more commonly, that word is **shot**); in stage productions, there are also stabs **in music** which open/close the show.

Comment: You're close to answering it.

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow which one? :P

Comment: can't say. HAHAHA

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow hmm.... I feel like it's number 3. I mean, when I go home, I take my shoes off and walk around the house all the time :D

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Okay I think I got number 3.... have I? (If I have, then you might want to change the wording only slightly in number 4.)

Comment: only no. 3 is correct, my friend. @user477343

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow for no. 2, I have added my previous thought. Is that correct?

Comment: taek moving and touching literally, and that is reall the answer. HAHA

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow yeah... it's what I originally thought, and was a little bummed out to see **KevinL**'s answer and realise that this was correct. Hahah, oh well :P